# Convert Java Spring data to Json and pass them to jsp with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-boot, jackson

In these days i'm developping an application with some new concept for me. The data access and manipulation is done (thanks also to your response here to my questions) and now i must try me myself to presentation layer/front end.

For our web app, my boss wants the processed data to be converted to Json and then presented to the user (interacting via browser) via Bootstrap.

Starting from the assumption that this world is new to me (in the sense that I've read guides and tutorials but never actually handed it over to), what is currently escaping is: how and if possible, give me information in Json format , represent them with a html table using Bootstrap, and whether this table can be generated dynamically once the data is obtained.

I expose the scenario more accurately: our application, developed using Spring Boot, basically queries the db and must show the video results to the user. The data access was implemented using the JDBC Template and everything proceeds during the test as it should.
As for the conversion of Json format data, I saw the Jackson framework and found on this site many and interesting examples of how to use it to convert the data produced into the above format. So there is no doubt about this.

Now suppose we have to submit this data to a JSP and want to use Bootstrap; How can i tell my application "get JSON and pager data in a table"?

For example, suppose you have the following Java class representing firewall objects:

```
/**
 * A firewall delimits a perimeter that needs to be protected and is characterized by
 * Id, ip, informations and name.
 * 
 * @author ***
 */

public class Firewall 
{
    private String id;
    private String ip;
    private String info;
    private String name;

    /**
     * Empty constructor, which instantiates a Firewall specimen without setting default values
     */
    public Firewall() {}

    /**
     * Constructor instantiating a Firewall specimen specifying its initial values
     * 
     * @param id the firewall's id code
     * @param ip the firewall's ip code
     * @param info the info about firewall
     * @param name firewall's name
     */
    public Firewall(String id, String ip, String info, String name) 
    {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.info = info;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Return firewall's identification code
     * @return firewall id
     */
    public String getId() 
    {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Set the firewall's id.
     * @param id the value for firewall's id
     */
    public void setId(String id) 
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Return firewall's ip
     * @return firewall's ip
     */
    public String getIp() 
    {
        return ip;
    }

    /**
     * Set firewall's ip
     * @param ip the value for firewall's ip
     */
    public void setIp(String ip) 
    {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    /**
     * Return firewall's info
     * @return info
     */
    public String getInfo() 
    {
        return info;
    }

    /**
     * Set the firewall's info
     * @param info value forfirewall's info
     */
    public void setInfo(String info) 
    {
        this.info = info;
    }

    /**
     * Return the firewall's name
     * @return name
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Set the firewall's name
     * @param nome value for firewall's name
     */
    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

Now, suppose that this is a simple controller to expose a list of all firewall with their data:

```
@Controller
public class PolarisController 
{
    @Autowired
    private FirewallsJDBCTemplate firewalls;

    @RequestMapping(value="/firewalls")
    @ResponseBody... //here I put the annotation for conversion using jackson
    public ModelAndView listFirewall(ModelAndView model) throws IOException
    {
        /**
         * This is the list of firewall obtained by the method implemented
         * in the DAO class.
         */
        List<Firewall> listFirewall = firewalls.getFirewall(null, null, null, null);
        model.addObject("listFirewall", listFirewall);
        model.setViewName("firewall");

        return model;
    }
}
```

Finally, we have a jsp called `firewall.jsp` (according to the name of model in the controller class) and in this jsp i must put a table to contain the data produced by the question of db and i must use Bootstrap in this page. How can i perform this task?

Comment: Why using `@RequestBody` if you want to send data? As this is a response to your request, don't you think that `@ResponseBody` is more suitable?

Comment: Sure; it's my writing mistake, i apologize and correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would not mix JSP views with an API serving JSON. I would suggest either using JSP/Thymeleaf views with the spring Model(AndView) OR building an API that serves JSON and then use a frontend javascript framework like angular to handle the view and model.

If I were in your situation i would move forward with Thymeleaf as a templating engine and drop the JSON stuff. Since you mentioned a lack of experience with frontend I think this route is less of a leap. Good examples can be found on the [Spring Github](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content/tree/master/complete)
found through [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion and thank you; I will confront with my boss and I will propose your idea.